# "paint bucket tool" for faces/modified dijkstra's algorithm with area weighting?

Tags: scripting, edges, faces, mathematics, 2d

I have a 2D mesh like the one below.
[image: completely empty mesh]

I want to create faces like those that would be created by a "paint bucket" tool in in a raster image editor; i.e., the faces should fill all the internal areas, but without overlapping or crossing edges. I've done this by hand to show what I mean:
[image]

Of course, my real mesh is more complicated and the manual filling would be extremely tedious. I started to write a script using Dijkstra's algorithm to, for a given edge, find the shortest loop between its two vertices that does not include the direct edge itself. Obviously, however, there are many cases in which the shortest perimeter or smallest number of vertices does not coincide with the desired result.
[image]

Obviously, the area of the resulting path has also got to be taken into account. Is there an algorithm out there that could do what I want? Math is not my strong point and I wouldn't even know how to begin going about this myself. Many thanks to anyone more knowledgeable who can set me on the right track.